# am comparing two dates in jasper server using jQuery but it is not comparing

Tags: jquery, jsp, jasperserver

Am comparing two dates in jasper server using jQuery but it is not comparing those dates. First i stored those two dates into two different variables like,

```
var fromDate = document.querySelector('#FromDate label.control input').value;
var toDate = document.querySelector('#ToDate label.control input').value;
```

now am comparing two dates as

```
if(fromDate>toDate){
    alert("To date should be greater than from date");
return false;
}
```

it works fine when we have same day like fromdate is "01-07-2013" and todate is "01-06-2013" it shows error but if i change like fromdate is "11-07-2013" and todate is "21-06-2013" it will not show error rather it display's report.

Comment: if you are more dealing with date then i recommend you to use http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fromDate ="11-09-2013";
var toDate ="21-06-2013";
var dtfrom   = parseInt(fromDate.substring(0,2),10); 
var monfrom  = parseInt(fromDate.substring(3,5),10);
var yrfrom   = parseInt(fromDate.substring(6,10),10); 
var dtto   = parseInt(toDate.substring(0,2),10); 
var monto  = parseInt(toDate.substring(3,5),10); 
var yrto   = parseInt(toDate.substring(6,10),10); 
monfrom = monfrom -1 ;
monto = monto -1 ;
var date1 = new Date(yrfrom, monfrom, dtfrom); 
var date2 = new Date(yrto, monto, dtto); 
if(date1 > date2)
 {
  alert("To date should be greater than from date");
  return false;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rmtGS/1/